# How to efficiently write unit test for complex business logic in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, automated-tests

I'm writing a room booking engine. There're 3 layers in play for the calculation : Rate Plan, Promotion, BookingQuery ( info of the request customers send in ).

When customers send in a booking query, containing info like booking date, check in date, check out date, number of people .. etc etc, this request will be passed through multiple layers of logic calculating from the Rate Plans and Promotions to give out a result ( whether or not room is available, how much is the price .. etc etc ).

I did write unit test for small calculation parts in my logic. However, I need to write an integration test, or a suite of integration test, containing hundreds of test cases of SPECIFIC input data and SPECIFIC expected output data ( not factory generated random data ). There are a lot of relationship within my entities, like $room->ratePlans, $ratePlan->promotions .. etc etc. Writing a single test case is exhausting enough, let alone hundreds.

What is the most efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

It is a very open question, i have been in the same place like you. I feel the best approach is to create helpers and structure your data according. Testing mainly consist of 3 steps, called arrange, act and assert.

Let's first focus on arrange, this is about creating your data. Create helpers for it, so you don't have to repeat your self. Multiple object returns is what i use, to avoid calling to many helpers.

```
public function createRoom(array $roomData)
{
    $room = factory(Room::class)->create($roomData);

    $ratePlans = factory(RatePlan::class, 3)->create(['room_id' => $room->id]);

    $promotions = factory(Promotion:class, 3)->create();

    $room->promotions()->saveMany($promotions);

    return [$room, $ratePlans, $promotions];
}
```

As the scope of this task is very vague, it is just to show ideas. This can then easy be utilized in your test.

```
public testRoomCreate()
{
    [$room, $ratePlans, $promotions] = $this->createRoom();
}
```

The act part of a test, calling the application is straight forward. Use `Laravels` inbuilt methods for this, which are implemented in the `Laravel` testcase.

For assertion, a good approach is to again create standardized methods to help you in your process.

```
public function assertRoomResponse($response, Room $room)
{
    $response->assertJsonStructure(
        [
            'id',
            'type',
        ]
    );

    $response->assertJson(
        [
            'id' => $room->id,
            'type' => $room->type,
        ]
    );
}

public function assertRoomDatabaseHas(Room $room)
{
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('rooms', [
        'type' => $room->type,
    ]);
}
```

There probably needs to be more logic related to relations etc. but if this is implemented you probably will have more assertions than most applications. This will make you able to write tests, that are fairly straightforward as shown below, but will require some maintenance to keep em generic. This thou solve your main problem of having trouble writing many tests.

```
public testRoomCreateWithTypeDouble()
{
    [$room, $ratePlans, $promotions] = $this->createRoom(
        [
            'type' => 'double',
        ]
    );

    $response = $this->call('POST', 'api/room', [
        'type' => $room->type,
    ]);

    $this->assertRoomResponse($response, $room);
    $this->assertRoomDatabaseHas($room);
}
```

Comment: Oh i haven't made myself clear. I need test cases with SPECIFIC input, and SPECIFIC expected output, not factory generated tests. Thanks for the answer, I will edit my question. If you have experience in this too please shed some light

Comment: But you can do that with factories to? it is a waste of time imo, by not using factories in tests.

Comment: Since it's a booking engine, I need to test the correctness of the calculation process, not just whether it's working. That's why i need specific input and expected output

Comment: And how does this not do that? there is assertion on structure, output and database context with tweaking you can adjust it to be more specific right now i only did it on type, since the question is very open ended

Comment: By using factories, I assume values in RatePlans and Promotions will be randomly generated ? How are you gonna test if it calculate correctly when you dont know exactly what the input is ?

Comment: you can pass input to that tbh if you are so new to testing, i think you are biting over more you can chew, start in the simple and build on top of that

Comment: yes, passing the input in is what i'm asking. How do we efficiently write test case like :
Rate Plan : - property 1 = X , - property2 = X2 ... etc .. etc
Promotion : property1 = Y1, property2 = Y2 ... etc etc
Expected calculation result : Result 1 = R1, result 2= R2

Comment: Did you look at the example, there is how you pass it to Room, do the same for rates etc.

Comment: I have also come across similar use case, where in I am also thinking if we can have any automation test strategy that can be built for such use cases. If you guys have some direction please do share.

Comment: I dont fully think i understand your situation can you elaborate?